# MYSQL calculate current year 1st month, 2nd month etc from old dates

Tags: mysql

I am looking for a query in MYSQL that would allow me to obtain the equivalent date for each month of the current year from old dates so for example The date: '2005-01-31' I would like to see the following populated into 12 separate month fields:

Jan - '2021-01-31',
Feb - '2021-02-28',
Mar - '2021-03-31'

I have attempted the following query however this only populates the same month of the old date but does however show the current equivalent day and year:

```
Select DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD('2005-01-31', INTERVAL (YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) - YEAR('2005-01-31') ) YEAR), '%Y-%m-%d') `date`;
```

'2021-01-31'

An example for a few months would be much appreciated and I should be able to adapt for the rest of the calendar year myself.

Comment: Relational databases are intended for the storage and retrieval of relational data

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT 0 n
         UNION ALL
         SELECT n + 1 FROM cte WHERE n < 11 )
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(@date, '2021-%m-%d') + INTERVAL n MONTH `date`
FROM cte
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d05df452e5ec5bb7bc262a7de1f13394)

---

> does not work for me on MySQL 5.x

```sql
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(@date, '2021-%m-%d') + INTERVAL n MONTH `date`
FROM (SELECT 0 n UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION 
      SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION
      SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 ) cte
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a1e3302869ee67cb634789e79142a6db)

Comment: The output values are exactly what i need, however does not work for me on MySQL 5.x, also i am trying to adapt to a case statement as follows:

case when its january then populate january equivalent of the olddate to a field called date1- so basically from the fiddle example you supplied it would show the contents of january from the table produced into date1 field if that makes sense?

Comment: @rob The answer updated. Next time provide your server version firstly.

Comment: My apologies, Thanks you this works for me but i'm still trying to add to an existing select list need this as a case stament for each month i attempted the following which i'm unable to do successfully:

SELECT
id,
olddate,

(
   CASE
    WHEN olddate <> ''
      THEN (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(olddate, '2021-%m-%d') + INTERVAL n MONTH `January`
FROM (SELECT 1 n) cte)) AS 'January'

FROM frn.mnt_mtx;